# How to not let '$' effect the insertion of a document in MongoDB using python or JS?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to dump data from one MongoDB database to another using  python and JavaScript. It changes the timestamp from unix to human readable form.
the data is something like this:-

```
[{'_id': {'$oid': 'qwer'}, 'playerId': 'abc', 'amount': 150.0, 'newValue': {'$numberLong': '150'}, 'reason': 9.0, 'type': 1.0, 'ts': {'$date': {'$numberLong': '1534423854022'}}}]
```

I used ast.literal_eval to sidestep the issue of '$' because it says there should not be a $ at the start both in Nodejs and Python

Python code

```
json_data = ast.literal_eval(data)
json_dump = json.dumps(json_data)
x= loads(json_dump)
my_collection.insert_many(x)
```

JS code

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
dbo.collection("Player").insertMany(body,{"ordered":false},function(err, res) {
if (err) console.log(err);
console.log("All document inserted");
});

mydb.close();
}
```

I want to use python and node.js both. I need to pull data and input in the exact same format as in the previous database.

Error Message is:-

```
Error: key $oid must not start with '$'
    at serializeInto (/Users/user/Desktop/mongo node aggregate/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:911:19)
```

Comment: *"because it says"* – What exactly is "it"? Can you show us the complete error message?

Comment: Apologies, I have added the error message